# Running a macro from within Add-In

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an add-in file and placed it in the Microsoft add-in folder. Inside  'ThisWorkbook' of the add-in, I have it installing a menu command button or uninstalling the button (Depending on if you are installing or uninstalling the add-in)

My Goal:

- I want another macro to run when I select the command bar button.
- I'm using .OnAction = "Test_Macro"

I need the Test_Macro to be inside the add-in.

My Problem:

- When I open up a random workbook, install the add-in, and press the button, I get an error saying "Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook".

But the macro is very clearly in this very same workbook. What is happening that I'm unaware of?

Comment: How do I access the standard Module of the Add-In

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the VBA editor, right+click on the add-in in the left pane  **VBAProject('add-in')** and highlight 'Insert' and select 'Module'

This is where you write the macro you want to use for .OnAction